# Tool to Visualize Descending Data in Intuitive Order of Importance

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot

## Stating the problem

I am attempting to write a code for an experiment in which a list of scores is input into a system and a list of accuracies is output. The nature of the input and output is crucial to the experiment, and I will provide a sample example for clarity.

For instance, consider the input scores list x = [0.0635, 0.0634, 0.0621, 0.059, 0.056, 0.054, 0.048, 0.046], and the output accuracy list y = [78.23, 80.12, 80.01, 80.99, 81.01, 80.98, 81.00, 82.02]. If we observe the values of x, we can see that they are in descending order. The accuracy values increase gradually, but after reaching a certain point (in this example, y=81.01), the accuracy values begin to fluctuate very sharply. Note that the values before y=81.01 can also exhibit fluctuations, but their rate is low and mostly shows an increasing accuracy trend.

[image: graph]

I have provided a graph below of the actual data to help illustrate the scenario. I used the plot() function in Matplotlib to plot the numbers, but I am searching for a visualization tool that can help readers understand that adding scores from highest to lowest leads to a gradual increase in system accuracy. After reaching a certain point, the accuracies start to fluctuate rapidly. However, I recognize that this graph visualizes the opposite way. Are there any better tool in python to vizualise it properly without altering the actual meaning of data?

I also want to find the accuracy value in list y after which the accuracies begin to fluctuate rapidly. In the graph, I marked a point with a red circle to denote a point after which the fluctuations increase sharply. I want to find that accuracy value from giant size of accuracy list output. Are there any possible way to achieve that number using python?

## What I tried?

I tried using plot() and bar from matplotlib to visualize the data without altering the meaning, but unfortunately, they didn't work for me.

To get the specific accuracy number after which accuracies start to fluctuate rapidly, I initially tried using a normal if-else condition. For example, if a new accuracy value is higher than the last accuracy, I logged the new accuracy value; otherwise, I ignored it. However, this approach doesn't work in cases where the new accuracy is slightly lower than the previous accuracy, but not significantly.

In the example from earlier (y = [78.23, 80.12, 80.01, 80.99, 81.01, 80.98, 81.00, 82.02]), we can see that after 80.12, the accuracy slightly drops to 80.01. But then it increases again to 80.99, followed by 81.01. After 81.01, the values start to fluctuate.

I want to find the accuracy value point before the start of rapid fluctuation of values. This is where I am seeking for help.

Comment: To find the red point, you might be able to do it using rolling statistics, like [moving mean](https://bottleneck.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#bottleneck.move_mean) and [moving standard deviation](https://bottleneck.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#bottleneck.move_std)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Later I got a python library called ruptures which helped me to detect change points. But, regarding to the visualization tool I still couldn't find any one which could satisfy my requirements.